# Object.limit(x).sum(:value) ignores the limit(x) -- why?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was compiling some site statistics using `HourlyMetrics` and found something curious.

Here's what the last 24 hourly stats are for my local dev environment.

```
irb(main):017:0> HourlyMetric.order('`to` DESC').limit(24).map(&:value)
  HourlyMetric Load (2.0ms)  SELECT `hourly_metrics`.* FROM `hourly_metrics` ORDER BY `to` DESC LIMIT 24
=> [0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I simply wanted the total, but I momentarily forgot the syntax and tried it two different ways:

```
irb(main):016:0> HourlyMetric.order('`to` DESC').limit(24).sum(&:value)
  HourlyMetric Load (2.3ms)  SELECT `hourly_metrics`.* FROM `hourly_metrics` ORDER BY `to` DESC LIMIT 24
=> 13

irb(main):018:0> HourlyMetric.order('`to` DESC').limit(24).sum(:value)
   (1.3ms)  SELECT SUM(`hourly_metrics`.`value`) AS sum_id FROM `hourly_metrics` LIMIT 24
=> 21
```

It seems that `sum(:value)` is generating `21` because that's the sum over *all* records in `HourlyMetrics`. So I understand where it's coming from, but can someone help me understand why `sum(:value)` isn't scoped when I use the `limit` scope?

Comment: That's odd. I got the same glitch with ruby 1.9.3 / Rails 3.2.13. `User.limit(1).sum(:id)` always returns the same (wrong) number

Comment: @MrYoshiji this is because of the way SQL works.  `User.limit(1).sum(:id)` will generate the SQL `select sum('id') from users limit 1` and the scoping `limit 1` is correctly applied to the result of the aggregate function `sum` here.  Just because it appears in one order in the ruby code doesn't mean the operations are performed in the same order in SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it *is* scoped, it's just that the scope is applied after the result of the aggregate value, and since the aggregate is across all rows in the table, it returns only a single row.

Your second statement is roughly analogous to:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT SUM(value) from hourly_metrics) limit 24;
```

and this is why the result is confusing you.

To reiterate - the aggregate function SUM returns 1 row, which is scoped with LIMIT 24

Comment: Your explanation makes sense! However, that's pretty unexpected/strange behavior. I get that ActiveRecord or whoever is lazily evaluating them and reserves the right to process them out of order for the sake of SQL optimization. However, I guess I would have thought that it would be smart enough not to do that when it would change the result. Does this qualify as a bug in ActiveRecord, or just a gotcha for programmers to watch out for?

Comment: @isthmuses It's classifiable as a gotcha, and to be fair ActiveRecord can't really be expected to catch this sort of thing as it's job is to be an abstraction layer between the database and you - it's going to assume that you know what you're doing so what you've asked it to do is what you want it to do :-)